LVM thin pool volume and BLKZEROOUT ioctl
I've just explored the following behavior for BLKSECDISCARD and BLKZEROOUT Linux kernel 6.4 ioctls with respect to LVM volume allocated in thin pool:

If I issue BLKSECDISCARD then the volume in the pool is unallocated, i.e. 0% of space is reserved for data (as one may expect).
If I issue BLKZEROOUT then the volume in the pool becomes fully-provisioned, i.e. lvs shows 100% space reserved for data.

The later behavior is questionable with regard of how the ioctl is implemented for other kinds of block devices (SCSI, eMMC, etc.). I see that the kernel tries to employ hardware commands like WRITE SAME SCSI command to perform the zeroout command. I expect that the result BLKSECDISCARD and BLKZEROOUT should be the same in the case of LVM thin pool.
For thin pool unmapped blocks are not really exists (compare with SSD, where discarded blocks are physically exists) and deterministically substituted by zeroes at read operation, so they are already guaranteed to be zeroes at read. Correct me if I am wrong, please.
So, what is the reason for such behavior?
